# While Loop Keeps giving Segmenatation fault

Tags: c++11, segmentation-fault

I am getting a segmentation error in this while loop, I am not sure why. The program is a lines of code counter. The while loop is meant to count the number of lines in a class so it just adds '{' to a stack and pops them out whenever a '}' comes up in the loop. When the stack is empty it should exit the while loop. Here is the while loop followed by the full code..

```
int countObjectLines(int index){
    stack<char> symbols;
    int i = index+1;
    int numberLines = 0;        
    symbols.push('{');
    while (!symbols.empty())
    {       
        string test(code[i]);
        for(int j = 0; j < test.size(); j++){               
            if(test[j] == '{'){
                symbols.push(test[j]);
            }

            else if(test[j] == '}' && symbols.top() == '{'){
                symbols.pop();                  
            }

            else{}
            numberLines++;
        }
        i++;
    }

    return numberLines;
}
```

Here is the full code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stack> 
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

//Lines of Code Iterator Class
class LOCitr{
public: 
    int count;
    vector<string> code;

    LOCitr()
    {
        count = 0;
    }

    ~LOCitr(){}

    //Trim White Space so line does not get counted
    string trimWhiteSpace(string const& str)
    {
        size_t first = str.find_first_not_of(' '); //find first character not a space
        if(first == string::npos) 
            return "";
        size_t last  = str.find_last_not_of(' '); //find the end of line before more whitespaces
        return str.substr(first, last-first+1); //create the string again with no white spaces
    }

    //Trim tab space from string
    string trimTab(string const& str)
    {
        size_t first = str.find_first_not_of('\t'); 
        if(first == string::npos) 
            return "";
        size_t last  = str.find_last_not_of('\t'); 
        return str.substr(first, last-first+1); //create the string again with no tab
    }

    //counter of lines
    int counter(string fileName)
    {
        string line;    
        string first_word = "";
        ifstream myfile (fileName.c_str());
        if (myfile.is_open())
        {
            while ( getline (myfile,line) )
            { 
                line = trimWhiteSpace(line);
                line = trimTab(line);
                if(line.empty()) //check for empty line
                    continue;     
                if(line[0] == '/' && line[1] == '/') //check for comment
                    continue;
                count++;
                code.push_back(line);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < code.size(); i++){
                cout<< endl << "code["<<i<<"] "<<code[i];
                stringstream stream(code[i]);       
                stream >> first_word;
                if (first_word == "class" || first_word == "struct")
                    {
                        cout << endl << first_word << i;
                        cout << "objectLines: " << countObjectLines(i);
                    }
            }

            myfile.close();
        }
        else return 0; 



        return count;
    }

    int countObjectLines(int index){
        stack<char> symbols;
        int i = index+1;
        int numberLines = 0;        
        symbols.push('{');
        while (!symbols.empty())
        {       
            string test(code[i]);
            for(int j = 0; j < test.size(); j++){               
                if(test[j] == '{'){
                    symbols.push(test[j]);
                }

                else if(test[j] == '}' && symbols.top() == '{'){
                    symbols.pop();                  
                }

                else{}
                numberLines++;
            }
            i++;
        }

        return numberLines;
    }


};


int main () {

    int count = 0;
    string file = "";
    LOCitr countMe;
    char input = 'y';

    //while loop to keep entering files to check
    while (input == 'y'){
        cout << "Enter file name:" << "\t";
        cin >> file;

        count = countMe.counter(file);    

        cout << endl << count <<endl;

        cout << "Enter another file? Enter Y/N :" << "\t";

        cin >> input;
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm *guessing* your calling `symbols.pop()` on an empty collection.

Comment: Sorry, the else{symbols.pop();} is actually just else {}, I had removed it but accidently clicked cntrl+z too far back. I changed it above.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a few problems with your code:

- Your loop condition is `while (!symbols.empty())`, but assuming the braces in your code are correctly balanced, your `symbols` stack will not become empty. Then what happens? You'll access `code[i]` where `i` is beyond the valid range of `code`.
- Your calculation `numberLines = (j-i)+1;` seems wrong because `i` is used to index lines and `j` is used to index columns. Not sure how you can subtract those and get anything meaningful.

Comment: I see the issue with numberLines, I changed that to numberLines++ and out it outside of the if else statements. But as far as the braces, what do you mean by that? I push in a left brace to start with so the stack has 1 item. After that if another left brace comes in it will push it and if a right brace comes in it will pop the stack. So if the correct number of right braces come up the stack will empty out, and there should always be an equal number because it is only iterating through a block of code which is an object.

Comment: Well, you start by pushing something onto the stack, making it not empty. How would the stack then become empty, if your input text has balanced braces?

Comment: Thanks again for helping out, if you look in the code I actually start on the line after the initial left bracket.

Comment: I actually just changed it

Comment: I actually just changed it to something else and it works now. Thanks again